# Facedetection in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, photo, face-detection

I'm currently working on a project, where I need to detect a face and then take a photo with the camera. (after the camera focused everything correctly).

Is something like this possbile in iOS?
Are there any good tutorials on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would suggest to use opencv for this as it has proven algorithm and fast enough to work on image as well as video

https://github.com/aptogo/FaceTracker

https://github.com/mjp/FaceRecognition

This solution will work for android too using opencv port to android.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for face detection.
Face detection example is also available in [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).
see last point in FilterShowCase example project of [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for face detection.

Comment: In actuality, my framework does no face detection at all (yet). All face detection is provided by feeding frames to Core Image.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 and Swift 3

You can check apple example you can detect face

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamBarcode/Introduction/Intro.html

you can select the face metedata to make camera track the face and show yellow box on the face its have good performace than this example

https://github.com/wayn/SquareCam-Swift